# How to update a table from the same table in the backup?

Tags: sql-server

I want to recover values from a table. I want to use the table from the backup. How to update a table from the same table in the backup?

This is the source

```
UPDATE DbCurrent.dbo.Table1 AS Curr 
SET Curr.Value1 =  
(SELECT Bck.Value1 
  FROM DbBackup.dbo.Table1 Bck 
  WHERE Bck.Id = Curr.Id 
  AND Bck.Id2 = Curr.Id2
)
```

How do you do that?

Comment: above query is looking fine what is the problem then

Comment: The problem is you can't use an alias by the updating table. Maybe I only forgot the word "AS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this will work fine

```
UPDATE Curr  
SET Curr.Value1 =  Bck.Value1
From  Value1 Curr
  INNER JOIN Value1 Bck
  ON Bck.Id = Curr.Id  AND Bck.Id2 = Curr.Id2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In stead of tt.Value1 do I have to use Bck.Value1. (That's maybe a copy of your source).

Comment: sorry now it has been modified.Yes it has been from my source @user1531040